# Unable to select the value from the drop list

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I know question is quite simple for you people to answer but, I got stuck at a drop list from where i wanted to select the birth Month.

I have been working on other websites but unfortunately could'nt get this to work.

I tried:

Click using different locators.
Using Action class to mover hover and clicking.
Using Java Script to select the month.

Strange thing is if I get the text of the WebElement i am able to do so, but not able to click on it.

url of the Application is : [a link](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ltmpl=default)!

This is when creating the account on google.

[image]

I was trying to select the Month from the list any month.

I have got TimeOutException when i wait until the box has the desired month.

Apart from that I dont get any error. The script always passes without making the selection.

I know the question is quite easy, but if anyone can help me get through it.

Thanks in advance.

```
<span id="BirthMonth" class=" form-error" aria-invalid="true">
<div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button jfk-select" role="listbox" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-activedescendant=":0" title="Birthday">
<div class="goog-menu goog-menu-vertical" style="-moz-user-select: none; visibility: visible; left: 0px; top: -82.2333px; display: none;" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true">
<div id=":1" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<div id=":2" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<div class="goog-menuitem-content">February</div>
</div>
<div id=":3" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<div id=":4" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<div id=":5" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<div id=":6" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<div id=":7" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<div id=":8" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<div id=":9" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<div id=":a" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<div id=":b" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<div id=":c" class="goog-menuitem" role="option" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
</div>
<input id="HiddenBirthMonth" type="hidden" name="BirthMonth">
</span>
```

Comment: pls add relevant html to the question.

Comment: Please see the html added. Alternatively it can be found with link in the post. Its the general gmail account webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you tried with sendkey? i hope by using sendkey it will work

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div[1]")).sendKeys("april");
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer Murali. But Unfortunately is just hovers to that month from the list but dont select it.

Comment: I tried this and working fine..give me the code which you tried.. I just get that registration page and used this sendkeys.. It selected month. I am not sure how you tried. Please provide your code

Comment: public void selectMonthFromMonthList(){
        birthMonthDropList.click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(months));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div[1]")).sendKeys("february");
    }

Comment: This just hovers the mouse to the selected month, but never actually click on the month.

Comment: please use it without click on that month drop down. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the update.It solved the issue, but could you please explain how does clicking makes difference, and the months locators are not visible until we click on the month drop down. So i thought it would make sense to click it first and then select.

Comment: If drop down is build with Select tag, then good to use Select class to select drop down values. If they are not built with select tag, then try with sendKeys(); . Here we are passing text to select in that drop down. so no need to click here. if it not works then go for click on drop down to display option and then click on required option.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. It has to work.

```
Select(driver.findElement(By.id("BirthMonth"))).selectByVisibleText("February");
```

if not, First please click on the dropdown list. Then store all the values in dropdown list into a array or list then select required value from the list/array.

Comment: Hi Shiva, Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately i tried all this, but it is not working. I am able to print the text for the tags when looping the list, but not able to select them.

Comment: I am able select month in Safari browser with the above code. But unable to in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can click first `BirthMonth` to open dropdown then click the month what you want. See below for selecting June:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#BirthMonth > div")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'June')]")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans. This also doesnt work. It gives me the following error:  rg.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (1154, 524). Other element would receive the click: <div class="goog-menuitem-content" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.19.346078 (6f1f0cde889532d48ce8242342d0b84f94b114a1),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Hi Mesut,  I used chrome and firefox browser.